# Pulseaudio header files under FC12

Tags: linux, header-files, pulseaudio

Greetings,

I'm trying to make use of the Pulseaudio APIs under Fedora Core 12.  To do a simple recording client, you're supposed to include these headers:

```
#include <pulse/simple.h>
#include <pulse/error.h>
#include <pulse/gccmacro.h>
```

However, I don't know where these files are under a stock FC12 installation.  Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks,
FM

Comment: Header file names didnt post well...

include <pulse/simple.h>
include <pulse/error.h>
include <pulse/gccmacro.h>

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/editing-help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$ yum whatprovides '*/pulse/simple.h'
pulseaudio-libs-devel-0.9.19-2.fc12.i686 : Headers and libraries for PulseAudio
                                         : client development
Repo        : fedora
Matched from:
Filename    : /usr/include/pulse/simple.h
```

Once you `yum install pulseaudio-libs-devel` (or the same using the package mangler of your choice), you should be all set.

Keep in mind that you should use something like `CFLAGS+=$(pkg-config --cflags libpulse-simple) LDLIBS+=$(pkg-config --libs libpulse-simple)` for portability.

Comment: Very kewl.  I was unaware of the "whatprovides" functionality.

Thanks,
FM

Answer (score 0):

According to the [spec file](http://cvs.fedoraproject.org/viewvc/rpms/pulseaudio/F-12/pulseaudio.spec?revision=1.106&view=markup), they're in the `pulseaudio-libs-devel` package (line 407).

Comment: the following command seems to work:

# yum install pulseaudio-libs-devel

Thanks!